# 'Monthly' and 'annual' as descriptors

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, suffixes

When I am describing a service that is billed for once a month I write, "This is a monthly service."  When describing a service that is billed for once a year I use, "This is an annual service."

Why would using "This is an annually service." sound incorrect?  It's as if 'monthly service' is used as shorthand for 'monthly billed service', and 'annual service' is used as shorthand for 'annually billed service'.  Is my problem that 'monthly' is used incorrectly in the first case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*An annually service* sounds wrong because it is wrong; you're using an adverb where you need an adjective (*annual*).

The trick is that the adjective form of "once a month", *monthly*, just happens to be the same as the adverbial form, *monthly*; the reader automatically assigns the word to its correct role based on its placement in the sentence.

Comment: The *-ly* adjectival suffix is also found in words that do not have an identical adverb, such as *earthly*, *manly*, and *homely*.

Comment: I should have realized that when I was trying to add tags to the question!  I thought, "Adverbs tag or Adjectives tag?  Why does it seem like both should be on here?"

Answer (score 3):

No, *monthly* is used correctly in the first case. You are comparing apples to oranges here (or adjectives to adverbs).

Per *The American Heritage Dictionary*, 4th edition, *annual* is defined as:

> adj. 1. Recurring, done, or pefomed every year; yearly: *an annual medical examination*

So *annual* is an adjective describing an interval. The word *annually*, on the other hand, is an adverb. Therefore, it cannot be used as you tried to in your sentence: *This is an annually service.* You could, as you suggest, write: *This is an annually billed service.* In that instance, the adverb *annually* is modifying *billed*, not *service*.

*Month* on the other hand is a noun, with the adjective form being *monthly*. Per *The American Heritage Dictionary*, 4th edition, *monthly* is defined as:

> adj. 1. Occurring, appearing, or coming due every month: *a monthly meeting; monthly rent payments.*

It is grammatically correct to use *monthly* as you suggested: *This is a monthly service.* (As others have mentioned, *monthly* is also an adverb meaning once a month; every month. But in this example, it is an adjective.)

Answer (score 1):

Because the adjective forms of *year* and *month*, are *annual* and *monthly* respectively, which is what you are using with the noun *service*.

The adverb forms are *annually* and *monthly*, which are used with the verb *billed*.

The fact that with *month*, the same form is found for the adjective and the adverb is what was throwing you off.